# get dataframe rows that contain values in a column that are close to those in a corresponding column in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes and I'm trying to search for incidences throughout each dataframe where two values under a specifically labeled column in each are close to one another but I don't see how to do this. I've tried isin but that seems to be too limited for what I'm trying to do here.

The key point in the problem is *close to*. I'm not only interested in incidences where the values are exactly the same.

i.e.

df1

```
   a 
0  10
1  100
2  1000
3  5000
4  6000
```

df2

```
    a
0   1
1   150
2   800
3   1002
4   5997
```

let's say I'm interested in rows in df1 and df2 where a is within +- 3 of each other, how would I then get a dataframe that is limited to only those rows with a corresponding value for a in the other such that I would get

df1

```
    a
2   1000
4   6000
```

and

df2

```
    a
3   1002
4   5997
```

?

Comment: Do rows need to sorted, such that the first row in `df1` is close to the first row in `df2`, etc.? And let's say `df1` also contained a 1001; would you need to have 1002 repeated in the corresponding row, or you just need sequences of values that are close to _some_ value in the other data frame?

Comment: No the rows don't need to be sorted. The values just need to be restricted to a specific column in each df but other than that any instance at all of 2 close values in the respective columns is what I'm after with no additional caveats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

THRESHOLD = 3
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10, 100, 1000, 5000, 6000]}, index=range(5))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 150, 800, 1002, 5997]}, index=range(5))

m = np.abs(df1.a[:, np.newaxis] - df2.a[np.newaxis, :]) <= THRESHOLD
df1_close = df1[np.any(m, axis=1)]
df2_close = df2[np.any(m, axis=0)]

print('df1_close', df1_close, '', 'df2_close', df2_close, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
df1_close
      a
2  1000
4  6000

df2_close
      a
3  1002
4  5997
```

Comment: May want to add some info on how the broadcasting works (e.g. "see the [docs on Numpy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html)").

Comment: Also you can get rid of the `numpy` import by using `abs`,`None` instead of `np.newaxis`, and the `.any` method on the arrays.

Comment: @Alex A matter of style, I guess, it's not like importing NumPy is incurring in any overhead since it's already used by Pandas, and the actual operations executed are the same, but yes, you could write it like that if you prefer (I personally find clearer explicitly using NumPy, specially in `np.newaxis`).

Comment: Agree! Just mentioning for OP.